# JComponent - set transparent background

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent

I have on a panel a JTable and a JLabel. I set it a background image but I can't get rid of that grey background from the table and label.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `.setOpaque(false);` on your JTable and JLabel